# I want to return the original df indexing for values returned by pd.groupby.max() function

Tags: python, pandas

The below code will create a table containing max temps for each day. What I would like to do is return the Index for all these max temp values so I can apply to the original df

```
        df = pd.DataFrame('date':list1,'max_temp':list2)
        grouped = df.groupby(by=date,as_index=False).max()
```

Comment: Apologies, temp not age

Answer (score 0):

You can define another column called `"index"` before sorting the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [7, 9, 3, 4]
list2 = [8, 6, 8, 9]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': list1, 'max_temp': list2})
df['index'] = df.index
grouped = df.groupby(by="date", as_index=False).max()

print(grouped)
```

Output:

```
   date  max_temp  index
0     3         8      2
1     4         9      3
2     7         8      0
3     9         6      1
```

Now, using `df.query`, we can get a `"date"` value by the `"column"` index:

```
print(grouped.query("index==0")["date"])
```

Output:

```
2    7
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Is this not just going to return the max value of the index after being grouped? I need the actual index

Comment: @BarryHotter Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('date')['max_temp'].idxmax()
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem i've found a great solution from the following link...

[Pandas groupby: how to select adjacent column data after selecting a row based on data in another column in pandas groupby groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54813114/pandas-groupby-how-to-select-adjacent-column-data-after-selecting-a-row-based-o)

(Although this doesn't seem to be the answer they accepted for some reason). Anyway, the following worked well for me if anyone finds them selves in the same position...

```
   idx = df.groupby('date')['max_temp'].transform(max) == df['max_temp']
```